# How can I pass information obtained from one apirest to another component using vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm in trouble I'm trying to pass information that gets from an api rest that's in a component A and store it in a variable of a B component 
i've dealt with this:

Componente A:

```
 data: () => {
    return {
      server: []
    };
  }



 axios
        .post("http://0.tcp.ngrok.io:13601//accountmanagement/login", LogInUser)
        .then(res => {
          this._UserLogin = res.data;
          if (
            this._UserLogin.credencial.rol.id_rol == 1 &&
            this._UserLogin.credencial.correo == LogInUser.correo

          ) {
            this.$router.push("admin");
          } else if (
            this._UserLogin.credencial.rol.id_rol == 2 &&
            this._UserLogin.credencial.correo == LogInUser.correo
          ) {
            this.$router.push("usuario");
            this.server = this._UserLogin

           //here I try to send the already verified user to another 
              component clear the request returns me a json if correct if 
             the registration is correct:

            EventBus.$emit('serverSelected', this.server);


          }
        })
        .catch(resError => {
          alert(
            "El servidor es en mantenimiento por favor intente mas tarde" +
              resError
          );
        });
```

Component B:

```
data: () => {
        return {
          server: []
        };
      }


  created() {

    EventBus.$on(
      "serverSelected",
      function(serve) {
        this.server = serve;
        console.log("The person is: ", this.server);
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }
```

including this does not show me any error or print me the information of the record that I try to send by eventBus.emit

Call eventBus:

```
import eventBus from '../../evenbus'
```

evenbus content:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

Comment: 1 - Did you call the API on `component A` correctly?  From the code, you posted it's just outside of anything make sure you trigger the API call.  2 - is the eventBus initialized/imported correctly

Comment: If I correctly made the call to my api now the call to the bus event right now I edit and update the information

Comment: I just updated it @Mehari

Comment: you can use Vuex to share state between components

Comment: all the examples of vuex are complicated I have already tried to implement it but it complicates me any examples that can support me ? @Loki

Comment: @StevenColocho there is a syntax error in the code you posted. Inside `then` section the conditionals (`if..esle/if`) have syntax issue. I think you want to pass the response regardless of the status hence Can you move the `eventbus.emit` logic out side of the block

Comment: Check this https://github.com/ooade/vuex-examples/tree/master/simple-todo

Comment: now I make it up thank you very much as I don't want to use localstorage to store those values :/ @Mehari

Comment: what was the issue? Does moving the emit part outside of the block fix the issue?

Comment: I don't fix it but I'll try to use vuex :) equally thank you very much for your help @Mehari